# How does a reference in closure and currying work in js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, currying

The following program confuses me very much, the console.log() were added by me.

```
function add(a) {
    console.log("1");
    var total = a;
    console.log("2");
    var _fn = function (b) {
        console.log("3");
        total += b;
        console.log("4");
        return _fn;
    };
    console.log("5");
    _fn.toString = _fn.valueOf = function () {
        console.log("6");
        return total;
    };
    console.log("7");
    console.log("_fn: " + _fn);
    return _fn;
}
```

When I ran add(1)(2), console showed:

```
1
2
5
7
6
_fn: 1
3
4
6
ƒ 3
```

My questions are:

1) in var _fn = function (b) {...}, what does _fn refer to in "return _fn" statement? If it refers to itself, then isn't it in infinite recursion like this

```
var _fn = function (b) {
    total += b;
    return function (b) {
        total += b;
        return function (b) {
            total += b;
            return _fn;
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
}
```

2) In console, it showed "_fn: 1" which means 1 was returned, but apparently, _fn (the function) was returned so that the calculation could keep going. So there is a conflict between the actual returned _fn and the value shown in console.

Comment: `return _fn` returns the *function* known as .. `_fn` *without* invoking it. This is called "springboarding": the function object is returned, and this can be invoked again *after the stack is unwound*. It is a way to get "Tailcall-like/indefinite" recursion.

Comment: Oh, my terminology was wrong, it's called ["trampolining"](https://www.datchley.name/recursion-tail-calls-and-trampolines/) (a good read), assuming such is the intent :}

Comment: Thanks for sharing the post. It's really good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in var _fn = function (b) {...}, what does _fn refer to in "return _fn" statement?

The return statement says the when this function is called, the return value from the function will be (a reference to) the function object itself. Note it returns the function object, *without calling it*. Just the object, no call. At least not yet anyway....

> If it refers to itself, then isn't it in infinite recursion like this ...

No, because the return value, the function, is not immediately called. It's kind of like doing this:

```
function g() {return g}
g()
```

Running that does not go into an infinite loop. You call the function g, and you get back g. You can do `g()()()()()()()` yourself, but that still "stops." Recursion is when a function *calls* itself, not *returns* itself!

> In console, it showed "_fn: 1" which means 1 was returned, but apparently, _fn (the function) was returned so that the calculation could keep going. So there is a conflict between the actual returned _fn and the value shown in console.

Well, it's probably not correct to say 1 was *returned*; instead the code forces all `console.log`s (and similar) to produce the current value of `total`. At the time you did your `console.log`, `total` had the value of your first argument, namely 1. You were pretty smart to print out all those numbers, so it should help your understanding. Check out that after the 7 was printed, you had not yet done the subsequent call in which the addition was done. That's why you saw 1.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that console.log() will run toString()/valueof() method. That's a really good answer.